# Is Kendall's tau adequate to test for a non-monotonic relationship?

Tags: correlation, ranking, networks, kendall-tau, ranks

### Goal

Networks can have so many nodes that it's hard to study them. That is why in some cases nodes are clustered together. I am looking at whether the betweenness of a node is maintained after the clustering. My question is: does the ranking of the nodes change because of the clustering? I did as follows:

1. Calculate the betweenness centrality of the nodes.
2. Cluster similar nodes
3. Connect the clusters. This creates an "aggregated network".
4. Calculate the betweenness centrality of the clusters.
5. Set the "new betweenness centrality" of the nodes as the betweenness centrality of the cluster they belong to.

### Question

Can I use Kendall's tau to see whether the ranking is maintained? I am not interested in seeing whether the betweenness centrality of nodes increases or decreases.

### Data

Here is my data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qjrcRSeXbK4bW-3xGlTDSd2UIcx3cOzi/view?usp=sharing. Every row is a node and every column is a clustering method.